# Trick to export-word without overwriting it in NetLogo

Tags: csv, export, netlogo

I was trying to use the following code to export-world in NetLogo without overwriting it:

```
export-world (land-use-map "land-use-map" date-and-time ".csv")
```

Where "land-use-map" is the final configuration of the patches, initially loaded with the [gis] extension as:

```
set land-use-map gis:load-dataset "land-use-map.asc"
```

But I run into an error whenever I do that. I wonder what is the problem with this code or if anyone could recommend any other way to do the trick?

PS: I am also loading the [csv] extension in NetLogo though I believe it is not required for this.

***ERROR MESSAGE:***

```
export-world: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
error while observer running EXPORT-WORLD
  called by procedure SAVE-EXPORT-RESULTS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go'
```

Comment: "I run into an error whenever I do that" is not very helpful unless you tell us what the error is...

Comment: Whoops, I will be more specific next time. Turns out the error was actually a typo, like @Alan pointed out...

Comment: Actually, it was not a typo (maybe it was but not just that). This is the error message: export-world: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
error while observer running EXPORT-WORLD
  called by procedure SAVE-EXPORT-RESULTS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-cmds), you will find a relevant example.  Note that you missed a few details: `export-world` takes only a string argument (the filename), which you construct with the `word` command, hyphens matter, and whitespace matters!  So you can try `export-world (word "land-use-map" date-and-time ".csv")`

Comment: Actually, I was too fast saying the problem was solved. This is the error message: export-world: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
error while observer running EXPORT-WORLD
  called by procedure SAVE-EXPORT-RESULTS
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go'

Comment: I believe this message means that you have constructed a filename that is not valid on your operating system.  Check the characters in the filename string you constructed against those allowed by your operating system.